# SQLAlchemy how to reflect many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I have two existing tables with a many-to-many relationship.
I'm trying to query from these tables, but it seems like I'm not able to reflect their many-to-many relationship.

Say I have two models with a reference table like this

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Table

Base = declarative_base()

family_tree = Table(
    "family_tree",
     Base.metadata,
     Column("brother_id", Integer, ForeignKey("brother.id"), primary_key=True),
     Column("sister_id", Integer, ForeignKey("sister.id"), primary_key=True),
)

class Sister(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sister'
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    brothers = relationship("Brother", secondary=family_tree, back_populates="sisters", 
    uselist=True)

class Brother(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'brother'
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    sisters = relationship("Sister", secondary=family_tree, back_populates="brothers", 
    uselist=True)
```

and I've populated all three tables. I now want to access the `brothers` info of a given `Sister` table entry.

I've tried to access the `sister` table like this

```
class SisterInspector(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'sister'
     __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

session.query(SisterInspector).first()
```

which works fine with

```
session.query(SisterInspector.id)
```

but throws an `AttributeError` when trying

```
session.query(SisterInspector.brothers)
>>> AttributeError: 'Sister' object has no attribute 'brothers'
```

I've tried to access my tables with this alternative way

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import Table, MetaData
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
foo = Table('sister', meta, autoload_with=engine)
print(foo.columns)
>>>> ImmutableColumnCollection(sister.id)
```

I understand that the relationship is not defined as a column, but

```
foo
>>>> Table('sister',...)
```

also makes no mention of said relationship. How do I get the many-to-many relationship out of my database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the SisterInspector class is doing for you, my SQLAlchemy implementation doesn't use a special inspector class like that -- and I wonder if the fact that it's using the same table name as your Sisters class is what's causing the issue.

Can you give us the output of something like

first_sister = session.query(Sister).first()

print(first_sister.brothers)